# Same behaviour with mousewheel and touchpad

Tags: scroll, swiper.js, mousewheel, touchpad

In [this demo code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mg9ssk?file=%2Findex.html) in the `swiper.js` API, you can control the slides with mousewheel. If you scroll the swiper with the mousewheel you can scroll each slide singularly. If you scroll with two fingers on the touchpad, you scroll multiple slides with a single gesture. Is there any way to switch just one slide each time the user scrolls with two fingers on the touchpad?

I tried to modify the `on scroll` function but I am not able to trigger it, stop it and enable back after just one slide.